# HMR not triggering sometimes for components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hot-reload

This has been baffling me for a few hours now & I can't seem to work out why. My project structure is below. *Sometimes* a change in `views/Dashboard/index.jsx` will trigger a hot reload & other times it will not. It's weird but when it works, after about an hour or so, it will just suddenly stop working...

**index.js**

```js
import 'react-hot-loader'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faChartBar, faThList, faCogs, faClipboard, faFilter, faNotEqual } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"

import configureStore, { history } from './redux/store'
import App from './App'

library.add(faChartBar, faThList, faCogs, faClipboard, faFilter, faNotEqual)

let store

function render(Component) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Component store={store} />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
}

configureStore()
    .then(_store => {
        store = _store

        render(App)

        if (module.hot) {
            // Reload components
            module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
                render(App)
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

**App.jsx**

```js
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// Routes
import routes from './routes'

const App = ({ store }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>{routes}</Router>
        </Provider>
    )
}

App.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object,
}

export default hot(module)(App)
```

**routes/index.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router'

// Components
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard'

// Views
import NoMatch from '../views/NoMatch'

export default (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
)
```

**views/Dashboard/index.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I make any change to the first 4 files listed (`index.js`, `App.jsx`, `routes/index.js`, `containers/Dashboard.js`) then the hot reloading works & the page is reloaded. However, if I attempt to make a change to `views/Dashboard/index.jsx`, for example, change "Hello World" to "Foo Bar" then the hot reloading is not honoured.

However I have now taken out the intermediary step of redux & changed the `routers/index.js` to use the direct component from `views/Dashboard/index.jsx` & it still does not reload.

How can this be? If I set the `component` on the `Route` to the container listed above, it hot reloads for that file but not this JSX one? Is this to do with the structure inside my main component `views/Dashboard/index.jsx`? If so, what? As it looks fine to me.

**EDIT**

My complete webpack config is:

**webpack.common.js**

```js
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const DotenvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader', // Using Babel to compile JS files
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 1000000,
                            name: 'img/[hash].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
        new DotenvPlugin({
            systemvars: true,
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')

const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    // https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#source-maps
    devtool: 'eval',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'development',
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        usedExports: true,
    },
})
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                "corejs": "3.0.0",
                "targets": {
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
}
```

I have updated the files listed to show what I currently have. This is a very weird error as sometimes the hot reloading will work & other times it will not. Hot reloading **always** works for files; `index.js`, `App.jsx`, & `routes/index.jsx` but sometimes it will work for `views/Dashboard/index.jsx` & sometimes it will not.

I was previously following the [Getting Started](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/) guide but [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/cvqdex/how_to_configure_reacthotloader/) thread helped me realise this was out of date. I have now just followed the [README](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/README.md) as is mentioned. I have also attempted to take snippets from this [article](https://developerhandbook.com/webpack/configure-webpack-4-hmr-scratch/) as well on setting up HMR with Webpack 4.

**Versions**

- `webpack`: *4.41.6*
- `webpack-dev-server`: *3.10.3*
- `babel-loader`: *8.0.6*
- `@hot-loader/react-dom`: *16.11.0*
- `react`: *16.12.0*
- `react-hot-loader`: *4.12.19*

I have the below response in the console so HMR is clearly enabled

[image]

I am trying to replicate exactly what is in the [examples](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/examples) as [recommended](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#troubleshooting)

Comment: Just looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/README.md). Did you try `export default hot(App);` in your root component?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well & still to no avail. I have only added that to the root component as it states